# How to automatically refresh getstream.io FlatFeed after a new post using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

I would like to understand how can I auto-update the feed after submitting the form through the `StatusUpdateForm` component. At the moment I have to refresh the page to see the changes.

In general, my task is to differentiate feeds based on the user's location, I requested extended permissions from support so that different users can post to one feed, and therefore I use the modified `doFeedRequest` parameters of the `FlatFeed` component to show the feed without being tied to the current user and it works.
I do not use notification, I want the posted messages to appear immediately in the feed.

If I wrote my own custom feed (`FeedCustom`) component to display data, it would work fine, but how do I make it work with `FlatFeed` of *getstream.io*? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StreamApp, FlatFeed, StatusUpdateForm } from 'react-activity-feed';
import 'react-activity-feed/dist/index.css';
// import FeedCustom from './FeedCustom';

const STREAM_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const STREAM_APP_ID = 'XXXXX';

const App = () => {
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [locationId, setLocationId] = useState(null);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const callApi = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8080/user-token')
        const userResponse = await response.json();

        return userResponse;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        callApi()
            .then(response => {
                const resp = JSON.parse(response.body);
                setLoading(false);
                setUserToken(resp.userToken);
                setLocationId(resp.locationId);
            })
            .catch(e => alert(e));
    }, []);

    const customDoFeedRequest = (client, feedGroup = 'timeline', userId = locationId, options) => {
        const feed = client.feed(feedGroup, userId);
        const feedPromise = feed.get(options);
        feedPromise.then((res) => {
            setData((data) => res.results);
        });

        return feedPromise;
    }

    return loading ? (
        <div>.... Loading ....</div>
    ) : (
        <StreamApp
            apiKey={STREAM_API_KEY}
            appId={STREAM_APP_ID}
            token={userToken}
        >
            {/* <FeedCustom dataFeed={ data } /> */}
            <FlatFeed doFeedRequest={customDoFeedRequest} />
            <StatusUpdateForm
                userId={locationId}
                feedGroup={'timeline'}
                onSuccess={(post) => setData((data) => [...data, post])}
            />
        </StreamApp>
  )
};

export default App;
```

My backend `https://localhost:8080/user-token` returns an object kind of:

```
{
    userToken: 'XXXXXXX'
    locationId: 'XXXXXXX'
}
```